# How to split string by empty line in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have string loaded from file:

```
var data = load("file.txt");
```

variable `data` is:

```
1
2
3

a
b
c
d
e
```

How to split this variable into two arrays like this:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

and

```
[a, b, c, d, e]
```

I try `data.split("\n");` and `data.split("\r\n");` but it doesn`t work.

Thank for help.

Comment: Have you tried with data.split("\n\n"); ?

Comment: Not working correctly. Added some special characters after each string. See: `(2) ["1↵2↵3", "a↵b↵c↵d↵e"]` - tested in chrome console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the space represents two line breaks you can try something like this:

```
var data = originalData.split("\n\n");
```

Then one line break:

```js
data.map((data) => data.split("\n"));
```

Answer (score 11):

Try with this:

```js
var str = `1
2
  3

a
b
c  
d
e`

var splitted = str.split(/\n\s*\n/)

splitted.forEach((capture, i) => console.log(`Capture #${i}:\n${capture}`));
```

This code splits the input in the occurrence of 2 carriage returns, optionally filled with any count of spaces.

Comment: you may want to append `.filter(x=>x.length > 0)` at the end of the incantation to account for whitespace at the start or the end of the string.